# Printing InnerHtml to Printer with formating intact in vb.net/C#

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, itext, gecko

In vb.net I need to print the contents showing in a browser control to printer.

I have used Gecko web-browser control in winform application and there is no direct way to print the page's contents.

Either way to print direct using `InnerHtml` or converting that `html` to pdf and then printing the `pdf` document.

currently I am using a third party library `ItextSharpe' but it gives errors.

```
public byte[] GetPDF(string pHTML) {
    byte[] bPDF = null;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(pHTML);

    // 1: create object of a itextsharp document class
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);

    // 2: we create a itextsharp pdfwriter that listens to the document and directs a XML-stream to a file
    PdfWriter oPdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);

    // 3: we create a worker parse the document
    HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(doc);

    // 4: we open document and start the worker on the document
    doc.Open();
    htmlWorker.StartDocument();

    // 5: parse the html into the document
    htmlWorker.Parse(txtReader);

    // 6: close the document and the worker
    htmlWorker.EndDocument();
    htmlWorker.Close();
    doc.Close();

    bPDF = ms.ToArray();

    return bPDF;
}
Byte[] bytes;
            bytes = GetPDF(browse.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
            var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(testFile, bytes);
```

but throws errors while parsing.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper' to type 'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph'.
```

[image]
[image]

I have seen different examples over web but this is totally different, the examples or duplicate answer is about to export panels or grids but this is dynamic HTML and i need to convert it to PDF or print directly the client area.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie ; see the requirements, where is the duplicate, is that of similar , i have gone through those solutions.

Comment: You are using `HTMLWorker`. As explained in the duplicate question, there is no support whatsoever for `HTMLWorker`. It's obsolete and it has been abandoned a long time ago. You should not be surprised that "it gives errors." As explained in the answer I refer to, `HTMLWorker` isn't the tool if you want to convert *dynamic HTML* to PDF.

Comment: Go to Google, and type "HTMLWorker is". You will see that Google will complement this sentence and suggest: "HTMLWorker is obsolete". When you click those keywords, you'll find hundreds of pages where I explain over and over again that `HTMLWorker` was replaced by XML Worker. Don't you understand how frustrating it is having to say the same thing over and over and over again?

Comment: I got the code from this Link : http://www.rswebsols.com/tutorials/programming/asp-net-generate-pdf-html-itextsharp

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Before posting or typing question, there was no clue that HTMLWorker was obsolete, right, i found the code from the link mentioned above and put a question with all done efforts, you should handle things politely, it does not harm you to guide with good way, rather this way.

Comment: 1. I am the original author of iText. Rather than having developers curse that "something doesn't work", I want to inform them that some things don't work, e.g. `HTMLWorker` doesn't work. Many other aspects of iText are great, but `HTMLWorker` isn't. 2. I am the author of the [official documentation](http://itextpdf.com) and I don't understand why a developer would rather believe what is written on an unofficial web site than what is made clear on the official web site: http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/parsing-xml-and-xhtml

Comment: People who do not read the official documentation are somewhat insulting because I spend many hours, days, weeks, months writing documentation that is made available for free on the **official web site** (not hidden somewhere on the internet). If you think I am not polite, think about how I feel about people who don't appreciate the documentation work I'm doing...

Comment: Ok Great, I will read this doc, and will implement accordingly, but i feel very upset when I expect some clue and being dealt a bit harshly,

Comment: You hurt easily. I didn't even mean to be harsh. When I'm harsh intentionally, it hurts much more. You should grow a thicker skin.

Comment: @DareDevil As you can see in the comments of that page, http://www.rswebsols.com/tutorials/programming/asp-net-generate-pdf-html-itextsharp#comment-16723, I commented on 22 March 2016 already that they use the obsolete `HTMLWorker`. So there really was a clue on a web page that you already had.